# Different font size for different font

Tags: fontsize, hebrew

I am using Hebrew and Latin script next to each other. The Hebrew font (ESRA SIL) is (like all Hebrew fonts) a bit bigger and clumsier than the latin one. So I want to reduce the fontsize of the Hebrew parts to 9pt.

This should be easy, but I don't get it.

my preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt,paper=24cm:17cm,pagesize=pdftex,DIV=calc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}

\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{EzraSIL} %%change to fontsize=9pt
```

Comment: After 4 years of membership you should know, that a code snippet is not enough. And nobody should need to ask you for a MWE …

Comment: Add the option `Scale=0.9`

Comment: Use `Scale=MatchUppercase`  for the hebrew font. Then it will be of the same height as the normal font.

Comment: Thank you both! It works great with the `Scale=0.9`option from @egreg – the `Scale=MatchUppercase`unfortunately doesn't work with my code.